# Not able to set the indent size in spacemacs

Tags: emacs

I am using [spacemacs](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs) (emacs advanced kit) and facing some issue with configuring tab size.

I have updated its configuration file to set up default tab size as following `~/.spacemacs`

[image: configurations for setting up default tab size]

but I see its not taking any effect. Does anyone know correct way to configure tab size?

Comment: In which modes do you want to configure your tabs ? Unfortunately each mode has its own way to handle tabs.

Comment: @syl20bnr  Yeah, I wanted it to set to JavaScript mode. I fixed this problem by following your suggestion. `(setq js-indent-level 2)`. Thnx and spaceemacs is awesome :)

Comment: You don't need a `progn` in a `defun` since it's body is an implicit `progn` :)

Comment: I'm surprised that it's extremely difficult to set 4 spaces indent in python mode. Why would spacemacs not follow PEP8 by default? Standard emacs with no configuration just works, but in spacemacs this seems impossible. I wasn't expecting Python to have become such a niche language...